# Flex pseudo-selectors

Tags: css, apache-flex

I have to add `* Required` to a ton of screens in Flex. In some places, I can't use more than one label. I need the asterisk to be as big as the text. The only idea I could come up with was:

```
.required:first-letter {
    font-size:30;   
}
```

Doesn't seem to work. Are pseuedo-selectors not implemented in Flex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, pseudo-selectors like that are unavailable in Flex. Flex CSS is very limited at the moment. Currently, in the 3.x branch of the Flex SDK, you can only use `.styleName` and `ComponentType` selectors.

According to [Adobe's Flex SDK Open Source site](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Flex+SDK), there will be new [advanced CSS selectors in Flex 4](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/CSS+Advanced+Selectors). The document does mention pseudo-selectors, but it appears that they will be available as a way to differentiate between component "states" rather than to access specific substrings in text. I'm guessing that your use-case is best implemented by using the `htmlText` property available on most text-based controls in Flex.